# compat-drivers-3.9 crash video card driver

Tags: linux, linux-mint, video

I try to install wireless driver on my linux with compat-drivers-3.9. After installing compat-drivers-3.9 linux , the video driver seems to be crashed. The resolution is not correct. How can I restore the previous video driver.

My environment: Mint Linux Intel i5 CPU, Intel Integrated Graphics

Comment: What wireless card?

Comment: @schaiba It is intel,Centrino Advanced-N +WiMAX 6250 driver iwlwifi